# how to check whether compose mail popup(Window)open or not in outlook using c#

Tags: c#, outlook, outlook-addin, outlook-2010

anyone know how to check whether the outlook new(Compose) mail window(popup) opened or not using c#?

note:i am using outlook 2010.

Comment: As a classic, any effort so far?

Comment: yes Soner.using inspector.newinspector.but i wont use it,because of raising that after outlook event.by the by why negative marks?

Comment: @ gustavohenke, Alexis Pigeon, Christoph,Mena, Spontifixus.i got the answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if I understood well your question but you could try something like:

```
//Check if the active inspector is a MailItem.
if(App.ActiveInspector().CurrentItem is OutlookApi.MailItem){
  //do something.
}
```

Or you can use the event [ItemLoad](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff868544.aspx)

```
private void OnItemLoad(OutlookApi.COMObject item){
{
  if (item is OutlookApi.MailItem){
    //do something
  }
}
```

I hope that this can help you.

Regards

Comment: Thanks Pedro.But how to i get mailitem.EntryId without using Inspector. or how to get current Active inspector in Inspector.CurrentItem?

Comment: You have a method in Application interface called [ActiveInspector](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.outlook._application.activeinspector.aspx) that returns the topmost inspector.

[Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.outlook._application_members.aspx) you have the allowed operations and properties that you can access using the Outlook Application interface.

Comment: i got it.thanks for ur relpy Pedro.Outlook.MailItem item = (Outlook.MailItem)Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveInspector().CurrentItem;